# Assigning an ID with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Alright, I'm a noob with javascript and jQuery.  I am working with the .dialog example on the jQuery UI page.   I have made some alterations in the markup and as a result I get a "*idName*null" for my first submission but there after, it does what i need for it to do.  It seems like the count starts at null then increases 1, 2, 3, so on...  Below is the code I'm working with:

```
$(function () {
    var rowID = document.getElementById("RowPlaceholder"),
        fName = $("#fName"),
        lName = $("#lName"),
        jTitle = $("#jTitle"),
        cPhone = $("#cPhone"),
        oPhone = $("#oPhone"),
        eMail = $("#eMail"),
    allFields =  $([]).add(fName).add(lName).add(jTitle).add(cPhone).add(oPhone).add(eMail),
    tips = $(".validateTips");
    function updateTips(t) {
        tips
        .text(t)
        .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        setTimeout(function () {
            tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
        }, 500);
    }
    function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
        if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " +
            min + " and " + max + ".");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 470,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Add Contact": function () {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(fName, "fName", 1, 16);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(lName, "lName", 1, 16);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(cPhone, "cPhone", 10, 16);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(oPhone, "oPhone", 10, 16);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(eMail, "eMail", 10, 80);
                if (bValid) {
                    $("#users tbody").append(
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td id=\"fName" + rowID + "\">" + fName.val() + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=\"lName" + rowID + "\">" + lName.val() + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=\"jTitle" + rowID + "\">" + jTitle.val() + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=\"cPhone" + rowID + "\">" + cPhone.val() + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=\"oPhone" + rowID + "\">" + oPhone.val() + "</td>" +
                    "<td id=\"eMail" + rowID + "\">" + eMail.val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>")
                rowID++;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });
    $("#create-user")
    .button()
    .click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById). It seems getelementById returns null in the case where the id is not found. My guess is that RowPlaceholder doesn't exist and is returning null. in JavaScript `null + 1` will return 1 which is why it starts working again after the first instance.

Comment: Yup, I just setup a form with id of RowPlaceholder and set it to hidden in css.  This did the trick.  Thanks for the proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

I just setup a form with id of RowPlaceholder and set it to hidden in css. This did the trick. Thanks for the proper direction